# Shadowsocks + v2ray server on my local computer at home. NOT on VPS. How to configure redirection of traffic from the server to the eth1?

Tags: ubuntu, routing, iptables

I created a shadowsocks + v2ray server on my local computer at home in a virtual machine. OS ubuntu 22.04. The ubuntu VM has 2 network interfaces: eth0 (192.168.1.10) and eth1 (192.168.2.10).
On the first router, which has a public IP, traffic redirection to 192.168.1.10 on port 16301 is enabled.

How to configure the shadowsocks server so that it correctly receives and processes incoming traffic from the shadowsocks client (phone) from the eth0 network interface (192.168.1.10) on port 16301?

Incoming traffic arrives at eth0 (192.168.1.10), but with the status SYN_SENT, it does not go anywhere further, and after 30 seconds it dies completely.
[Attached a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK1Sq.jpg)

After this, incoming traffic from the shadowsocks server needs to be redirected to eth1 (192.168.2.10).
And in the opposite direction, send outgoing traffic from eth1 (192.168.2.10) to the shadowsocks server, and then the traffic needs to be returned to the shadowsocks client. Make sure that traffic does NOT go directly to eth0 (192.168.1.10).

Shadowsocks server starts successfully. [Here is the config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukLq1.jpg). There is no v2ray config, only an exe file.

Do I need to fully specify the IP, mask and gateway for network interfaces in the “ipv4 routes” section? Or do you only need to specify the ip and mask for both interfaces?

[eth0 (192.168.1.10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpaeB.jpg)

[eth1 (192.168.2.10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc9x5.jpg)

Do I need to set up a firewall? It is now disabled.

I tried different "iptables" commands and no success. I didn’t save which ones I used.

[I drew approximately how all my devices are connected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ3U8.jpg)

I have zero experience with linux. Please help.

It feels like no one has ever made a shadowsocks server on their computer at home. I searched and didn't find anything at all. Or is it so simple that no one has any questions.